# SQL select query with multiple conditions issue

Tags: mysql

I have a problem with a SQL select query, I can't figure out what it needs to be.

This is what my `items` table look like:

```
| id |   i_id   |      last_seen       |   spot    |
----------------------------------------------------
| 1  |   ls100  | 2017-03-10 15:30:40  |  spot800  |
| 2  |   ls100  | 2017-03-10 16:20:15  |  spot753  |
| 3  |   ls200  | 2017-03-10 16:33:10  |  spot800  |
| 4  |   ls300  | 2017-03-10 15:30:40  |  spot800  |
| 5  |   ls300  | 2017-03-10 12:10:30  |  spot800  |
| 6  |   ls400  | 2017-03-10 10:30:10  |  spot800  |
```

This is what I'm trying to obtain:

```
 | id |   i_id   |      last_seen       |   spot    |
 ----------------------------------------------------
 | 3  |   ls200  | 2017-03-10 16:33:10  |  spot800  |
 | 5  |   ls300  | 2017-03-10 12:10:30  |  spot800  |
```

So I need to have the rows where spot`= 'spot800', last_seen = MAX(but only if the DateTime is the newest compared to all spots with the same`i_id`), and at last the DateTime must be bigger than '2017-03-10 11:00:00'.

This is what I have so far:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM items
 WHERE spot = 'spot800' 
HAVING MAX(`last_seen`) 
   AND `last_seen` > '2017-03-10 11:00:00'
```

Comment: whether your query returning any records?

Comment: You forgot grouping by i_id

Answer (score 2, accepted):

E.g.:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS my_table;

CREATE TABLE my_table
(id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
,i_id   INT NOT NULL
,last_seen       DATETIME NOT NULL
,spot    INT NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO my_table VALUES
(1,100,'2017-03-10 15:30:40',800),
(2,100,'2017-03-10 14:20:15',753),
(3,200,'2017-03-10 16:33:10',800),
(4,300,'2017-03-10 15:30:40',800),
(5,300,'2017-03-10 12:10:30',800),
(6,400,'2017-03-10 10:30:10',800);

    SELECT [DISTINCT] x.* 
      FROM my_table x
      LEFT
      JOIN my_table y
        ON y.i_id = x.i_id
       AND y.last_seen < x.last_seen
     WHERE x.last_seen > '2017-03-10 11:00:00' 
       AND x.spot = 800
       AND y.id IS NULL;
----+------+---------------------+------+
| id | i_id | last_seen           | spot |
+----+------+---------------------+------+
|  3 |  200 | 2017-03-10 16:33:10 |  800 |
|  5 |  300 | 2017-03-10 12:10:30 |  800 |
+----+------+---------------------+------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: I still get id 1 returned and this one shouldn't be returned because its date is  older than that from id 2

Comment: Also the date in row 2 should be '2017-03-10 16:20:15'

Comment: @SerAkd You're welcome. You wanted rows with ids 3 & 5. It makes no sense (to me) to return a time and id that don't correspond.

Comment: Indeed I wanted those rows, but when I execute the query it also returns id 1?

Comment: Plainly, that's not true. See above.

Comment: I don't do pictures, sorry. See rextester or sqlfiddle.

Comment: It is a screenshot from this query:
SELECT DISTINCT x.*
FROM `items` x
LEFT
JOIN `items` y
ON y.i_id = x.i_id
AND y.last_seen < x.last_seen
WHERE x.last_seen > '2017-03-10 11:00:00'
AND x.spot = 'spot800'
AND y.id IS NULL
And the result

Comment: I cannot replicate the finding, which is why I say provide a rextest or fiddle.

Comment: I think it works..THANKS! Had to switch the y.last_seen with x.last_seen in the line: y.last_seen > x.last_seen

Answer (score 0):

Use `MAX` and `GROUP BY`.

```
SELECT id, i_id, MAX(last_seen), spot  
FROM items
WHERE spot = 'spot800'
AND last_seen > '2017-03-10 11:00:00'
GROUP BY id, i_id, spot
```

Comment: because that matches your logic, id 1 is returned because it is the MAX last_seen for the ls100s

Comment: My apologies, I forgot to edit it, id 1 shouldn't be the MAX last_seen

Comment: If i use : GROUP BY `i_id` instead of GROUP BY `id`, `i_id`, `spot` then it returns the rows with id 1,3 and 5

Answer (score 0):

There is several things wrng with your statement.

Firstly, **HAVING** must be accompanied with a GROUP BY clause, so it's not what you are looking for.

Also, MAX is an aggregate, not a boolean, function. That is, it cannot be used in filters, such as a where clause or a having clause. Also, if it did work, MAX would only return the entry that contains the time as '2017-03-10 16:33:10'. Not what you expected.

Try this instead:

```
SELECT * FROM items WHERE (spot='spot800' AND last_seen > '2017-03-10 11:00:00');
```

Comment: HAVING doesn't have to follow a GROUP BY clause - although that is its primary purpose. And your solution is incomplete, but otherwise, good.

Comment: This query returns the rows with id 1,3,4,5 and it only needs to return the rows with id 3 and 5